# Multivariate random variables with scipy.stats rvs() function

Tags: python, random, distribution, scipy.stats

The `scipy.stats` suite of statistical distributions  (`scipy.stats.norm`, `scipy.stats.uniform`,  `scipy.stats.t` etc) all produce univariate data series using their own `.rvs()` function, and only one has a multivariate rendition: `multivariate_normal`, which corresponds to `numpy`'s `numpy.random.randn((N,K))`. In fact, virtually all of the statistical distributions found in `numpy.random` can produce multivariate data.

How can I extend the univariate distribution functions found in `scipy.stats` to multivariate number generation, given that it possesses some distributions not found in `numpy.random` like `johnsonsu`? Must I manually make a loop function myself that concatenates multiple univariates together? what should that look like

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to pass a `size` parameter to `rvs`.  For example:

```
from scipy import stats

stats.norm.rvs(size=10)
```

will give you a vector filled with 10 standard normal variates.

note that multivariate means something specific in statistics, not just [IID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) copies of the same (which is what `size` does).  e.g. the `cov` parameter to `multivariate_normal` specifies the covariance matrix of all variates within one draw.

as another example, `multinomial` is similar, but the parameters of the distribution are obviously different.

```
stats.multinomial.rvs(n=5, p=[0.5, 0.5], size=10)
```

tells you how many heads & tails you get from throwing a coin 5 times, repeating this 10 times.  i.e. the rows are separate draws, the columns are the values within a draw